# Migrating from Babylonnet to Carthage

Tags: tezos-client

I just started learning Tezos programming a few weeks back and had set up my iMac with Babylonnet. After the Carthage activation, now I am trying to migrate from Babylonnet to Carthage. As I couldn't find the instructions for migration, I did the following steps:

1. Stopped Babylonnet (but didn't delete the docker images)
2. Followed the instructions at http://tezos.gitlab.io/introduction/howtoget.html to get Carthage setup using docker image.
3. Started Carthage

When I am trying to start, getting the following Warning

> "Host is already in use by another container"

and also the Error:

> ERROR: for node  Cannot start service node: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint carthagenet_node_1 (b99c2ee54e54d0ec2318a0dcb15e2ffd774ae1bca0e8571013872cce8bc28d39): Bind for 0.0.0.0:19732 failed: port is already allocated

Do I need to delete Babylonnet nodes/data completely and setup Carthage with the complete sync process again? As I understand, new protocol upgrades should be seamless and wouldn't require deleting old data.

Please help and let me know where I can read more about the upgrade process.

note: I am using iMac 2019 with VirtualBox/Ubuntu.

Thanks
Nauman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your stopped Babylon container is still causing a conflict. Did you create a docker volume to store the node data? If not, then you'll have to delete the babylon completely and start new carthage container.

You are correct that Tezos has a built-in upgrade system for nodes. But using docker makes the process much more difficult to manage since none of the tezos-docker documentation talks about best practices.

Before you start carthage, you should create a new docker volume, then bind that volume to the new container using `-v carthageVolume:/var/run/tezos` This way, you can stop/delete the node container and all data will be safe for upgrading the container in the future.

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense now. No, I didn't create the docker volume. I will try your recommendation of docker volume.

Comment: @Nauman Please mark as answered if the above is good. Thanks.